# Bitwarden Self-Hosted on Debian 10x 64 Buster with Apache2

Tags: linux, nginx, debian, apache2, 64-bit

I installed bitwarden on my VPS following this link https://bitwarden.com/help/article/install-on-premise/. I got an error at the end while running `bitwarden.sh start`
The error message was :

```
Creating bitwarden-nginx         ... error

ERROR: for bitwarden-nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint bitwarden-nginx (MYHASH): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint bitwarden-nginx (MYHASH): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

I have changed the hashes because I don't know if they should be public or not. From my original hash it is now "MYHASH"

I want to install bitwarden on apache2 and not nginx.
How can i troubleshoot this error and is it necessary to install nginx?

Comment: You can do a manual installation following the documentation at the bottom of the page you linked to. You'll have to convert the nginx configuration from https://github.com/bitwarden/server/tree/master/util/Setup/Templates to an Apache equivalent. If you feel that's too complicated just transition to nginx, you won't regret it in time.

Comment: i had tried to configure my website with nginx and certbot but after i did it and tried to host searx on it it got really fucked up so i switched to cloudflare and apache

Answer (score 0):

Well, short answer is to just change port on which embedded nginx is listening and forward via apache all connections